# How to prevent users to change url parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am developing a site where I am sending parameters like ids by url. I have used urlencode and base64encode to encode the parameters.

My problem is that how can I prevent the users or hackers to play with url paramenters Or give access only if the parameter value is exist in database?

I have at least 2 and at most 5 parameter in url so is this feasible to check every parameter is exist in database on every page?

Thanks

Comment: You should always check parameters.

Comment: Any type of encoding of the parameters in the query string is simply a joke. *Do not* rely on this for security. You *cannot* trust **any** input from the user (not even `$_POST`). Verify *all* parameters.

Comment: thanks, but is this better way to check all parameters on every page, I think it will affect on speed of execution of page.

Comment: Input sanitation/validation should be your last concern regarding speed. Optimize your database queries instead of worrying about this.

Comment: @Sachin What are the parameters? If you explain, better advice can be given. If they are simply IDs for fields in the database, sanitize them, then make the query. If no row can be found, show an error.

Comment: @Jonathon ReinhartYes they are simply IDs or primary keys of tables, Can you tell me how can I sanitize them, Just check them are they exist in database or anything else?

Comment: No, just make sure they are integers. Otherwise one could inject SQL into your queries.  Perform the query with whatever ID they give you. Then handle errors for missing rows accordingly.  This gets the "exists in database" check for free.

Comment: @Jonathon Got it, I will do that, but what about the page execution time?

Comment: Get it working correctly now. Optimize later.

Comment: I have done that and its working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot stop users from playing with your `QueryString`.

You can only validate them in your script before you do anything with them.

This also applies to POSTed variables as well, they can be hacked almost as easily.

So Validate, validate, validate.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you concern about internal data put them in a session variable. But remember always everything out there is evil. You alway have to check if any input contain SQL injections.

If you use session cookies make sure that hey are http only. So no JavaScript can copy the session cookies and if possible never put them in the url itself. It's quiet easy to copy the url and hijacking a existing session.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on what you are using the parameters for. If they are private and should not be accessible to other users, you should link the data to a specific user and deny access to everyone who isn't authenticated as the correct user.

Also, always remember to sanitize user inputs, which includes URL parameters. Use prepared statements when passing user inputs to a database and encode it before serving it back to other users.

Answer (score 0):

The best I would to is to validate on server side for the user entered paramters. Also I would check if the requests originated from my site (XSS & CSRF). Transmitting data post would be good but provides minimal security IMHO.
Therefore, validate and authenticate the originating location to ensure that it does not come from an outside source